# How to send attachments using Swift mailer library?

Tags: php, swiftmailer

Please let me know if any eg. how to send attachments(doc/image etc.) using Swift library?

Answer (score 5):

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject here', 'Body here');

$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('/path/to/file'));
```